# Subspace test for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, likelihood-ratio, lagrange-multipliers

Subspace test for multivariate normal distribution
Suppose $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. observations from a multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is known. Furthermore, assume that $R$ is a given matrix and $r$ is a given vector. Use the likelihood ratio procedure to produce a test statistic for

$$H_0 : R\mu = r\quad\text{vs}\quad H_1 : R\mu \neq r.$$

Give explicit formulae for the test statistic and the critical values.

I am studying completely different things but this assignment is part of a seminar which is only for some additional points. I would be very grateful if someone could explain the answer to me step by step.

Comment: This seems a homework. Are you familiar with the likelihood ratio test? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: The answer from here helps me a bit, but I need a more detailed explanation in the first part (answer with likelihood ratio test, the first answer) , I don't understand it well enough. Otherwise, I am familiar with the Likelihood-ratio test.